# BeautifulSoup поиск и вывод ключа значения в source

Tags: python

Всем привет! Такая задачка: нужно спарсить страницу html, найти значение, например getvalue_new=133, и записать это значение 133. как парсить классы понятно:

```
soup.findAll(attrs={"class":"getvalue_new"})
```

но тут значение не одно в классе, а купа данных. а нужно вытащить цифру только одного getvalue_new. Не подскажете решение?
пример кода:

```
<ul class='class1'>

                <li><a данные данные ненужные данные getvalue_new=133 данные данные всякий хлам
                <li>
                    опять хлам итп
                </li>

        </ul>
```

в итоге хочу переменной присвоить значение getvalue_new, т. е. 133

Comment: вы можете привести пример HTML'а и желаемый результат?

Comment: поправил вопрос

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Метод `.findAll`, в отличии от `.find`, возвращает список, даже если элементов ноль или один (вернет пустой список или список с одним элементом, соответственно)

Вам нужно взять по индексу нужный вам элемент массива, например так, если нужен самый первый

```
soup.findAll(attrs={"class":"getvalue_new"})[0]
```

Но я не совсем понял что вы хотите найти.
Ваш пример найдет теги типа `<div class="getvalue_new"></div>`.

Если вам нужны теги типа `<div getvalue_new="133"></div>`, то вам нужно искать так

```
`soup.findAll(attrs={"getvalue_new": True})[0]`
```

И потом к вашему атрибуту можно обратится так

```
`soup.findAll(attrs={"getvalue_new": True})[0]['getvalue_new']`
```

Comment: то что надо! помогите разобраться в конструкции: если bs находит attr getvalue_new, то присваивает переменной значение по порядку 0. что делает эта часть ['getvalue_new']?

Comment: @dimahimma  ['getvalue_new'] берет значние атрибута  getvalue_new. 
А 0 вы можете заменить на перебор всех значений циклом.

Comment: ну так вот эта часть уже взяла нулевое значение и присвоила переменной soup.findAll(attrs={"getvalue_new": True})[0], зачем эта часть ['getvalue_new']

Answer (score 3):

Мне вот больше нравится работать не с функциональными методами для поиска, а через `xpath` или `css-селектор` – они нагляднее и везде используются.

Пример `css-селектора`:

```
html = """
<ul class='class1'>
    <li><a getvalue_new="133">
    <li>опять хлам итп</li>
</ul>
"""

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
root = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

a_value = root.select_one('a[getvalue_new]')
print(a_value['getvalue_new'])  # 133

a_value_list = root.select('a[getvalue_new]')
print([a_value['getvalue_new'] for a_value in a_value_list])  # ['133']
```